# Isomorphism from the multiplicative group U7

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be the group $Z_6$ under addition. Find all the isomorphisms from the multiplicative group $U_7$ of units in $Z_7$ to H?

This is one of the practice question for my exam tomorrow.. I dont understand what the author means by $U_7$ of units in $Z_7$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to say that every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ has a multiplicative inverse, so the group $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ has order $6$.  You can also check that $3$ has multiplicative order $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.  It follows that $\mathbb{Z}_7^*\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Hence, the question reduces to finding all automorphisms of the group $\mathbb{Z}_6$.  Since an automorphism of a cyclic group is determined by where a generator is sent, and since there are $\varphi(6)=2$ generators of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ (where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)), it follows that there are two automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.  Translating this back to answer your question, we have the two maps:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}f_1:\mathbb{Z}_7^*&\rightarrow &\mathbb{Z}_6\\
3&\mapsto &1
\end{array}$$
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}f_2:\mathbb{Z}_7^*&\rightarrow &\mathbb{Z}_6\\
3&\mapsto &5
\end{array}$$

Now $5$ also has multiplicative order in $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$, so we could have just defined the above maps by deciding where to map $5$.  Suppose we did this to obtain the following isomorphisms

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}g_1:\mathbb{Z}_7^*&\rightarrow &\mathbb{Z}_6\\
5&\mapsto &1
\end{array}$$
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}g_2:\mathbb{Z}_7^*&\rightarrow &\mathbb{Z}_6\\
5&\mapsto &5
\end{array}$$

Then, noticing that $3\equiv5^5\mod 7$, it follows that $g_1(3)=g_1(5^5)=5\cdot g_1(5)=5\cdot1=5$ (remember that the group operation in $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is multiplication, while the group operation in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is addition), so that in fact, $g_1=f_2$.  Similarly, you can show that $g_2=f_1$ and thus we have not defined any new automorphisms.

Comment: Thankyou very much Jared. I just have one more question if you have the time. What if there were more elements in $Z_7$ that had order $6$ (lets say both $5$ and $3$ had order $6$) how would the mapping work then. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome Kj.  I will answer your second question with an edit to my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The author means, those elements of ${\bf Z}_7$ that are invertible under multiplication modulo $7$. Do you know what the multiplicative identity is in ${\bf Z}_7$? Knowing that, can you figure out which elements have multiplicative inverses?

Comment: I believe every element, except $[0]$, of $Z_7$ have a multiplicative inverse and the element $[1]$ is the identity. Where do I go from here ?

Comment: "Where do I go from here ? " I re-read my comment and thought this may come across as rude but cant edit for some reason. I meant is you kindly give me another hint.

Comment: You probably know that $H$ is cyclic. There won't be any isomorphisms if $U_7$ isn't also cyclic, so first check that. If it is cyclic, then convince yourself that any isomorphism must take a generator of one group to a generator of the other, and that once you know what an isomorphism does to a generator you know what it does to everything. Then take it from there.